# Using a subset of GetHashCode() to increase AzureTable performance through partitioning

Tags: c#, .net, performance, azure, azure-table-storage

Generally speaking, Azure Table IO performance improves as more partitions are used (with some tradeoffs in continuation tokens and batch updates I won't go into).

Since the partition key is always a string I am considering using a "natural" load balancing technique based on a *subset* of the `GetHashCode()` of the partition key, and appending this subset to the partition key itself.  This will allow all direct PK/RK queries to be computed with little overhead and with ease.  Batch updates may just need an intermediate to group similar PKs together prior to submission.

Question:

- Should I use `GetHashCode()` to compute the partition key?  Is a better function available?
- If I use `GetHashCode()` does it matter which character I use for my PK?
- Is there an abstraction for Azure Table and Blob storage that does this for me already?

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use `GetHashCode` as its value is only guaranteed to be stable in the current AppDomain. Otherwise, it can change anytime.

Use a hash function which you control or which is standardized. Google has put out a set of hashes for this purpose including "murmur hash".

What should you partition (and hash) on? That depends on your query patterns. It absolutely cannot be answered without looking at your query patterns. In general, try to partition on something that is a predicate in almost all of your queries.

Comment: Ahh you're right, I remember hearing that I shouldn't save a HashCode() to disk now you mention it.

Comment: Just a clarification, I'm not asking what (in my dataset) should be used as a partition key.  Instead I'm saying my PK is "SomeStudentID".  Pretend the murmur hash is "ASDF123".  I only want 36 partitions. Should the PK be SomeStudentIDA or SomeStudentID3 where the appended character comes from the murmur hash (or similar), but evenly and consistently distributes data.  Since I'm only using one char I'm trying to decide which character to use.  The is algorithm-specific and am looking for advice.  How should I rephrase the question?

Comment: I sense there is a misunderstanding, not sure where. You could choose (Hash(StudentID) % 36) as the partitioning key and StudentID as the PK. Would that work?

Comment: If you try to limit the number of partitions you create you may create performance issues in the future.  What works fine with just 1k items per partition will not work so well with 10k items per partition.  If you're going to do this, be aware that you'll want some way of managing the size of these partitions or be very sure of what you data growth will look like.

Comment: @knightpfhor I'd love to encapsulate this logic into a library everyone can use so I thought about your concern a bit.  What do you think of a pre-query processor that looks up & caches the partition count per table? Since partition requirements can change over time, perhaps a background worker can migrate the data to the new partitioning scheme as needed.  To keep in-flight queries running perhaps a pre-query processor would track the new and old partition counts and update both on writes (but only "read" from the old one until migration is complete).  Just a thought.

Comment: I think that would work technically, but it sounds like lots of work and I don't see too many advantages for doing so. In my experience you're better off just designing your PK so they're naturally smaller and scallable.  You mention students in your questions, so for example year they started might be a nice PK as it doesn't change, it will get big, but hopefully not too big and you'll naturally get new partitions over time.